# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined while try to change style of given element

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I try to learn javascript and ajax, so I write any script where I want to change style of given element in form. I've trying to do this since 2 days but without any effect - I still have error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". I include my html and js code below. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

html:

```
<div id="registerNewUser" class="tabContent">
                  <h1>Registration form</h1>
                  <form action='#' name='registerForm' id='registerForm'> 
                    <table style='width: 25%;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #000;" id='name' name='name' size ="10" onClick='changeStyle(this.id);' onBlur='checkFieldName();'></td>
                            <td><div id='divName'></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Second Name:</td><td><input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #000;" id='secondName' name='secondName' size="10" onClick='changeStyle(this.id);' onBlur='checkFieldSecondName();'></td>
                            <td><div id='divSecondName'></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password:<sup style='cursor: help' title="Password must have at least 6 characters">*</sup></td><td><input type="password" style="border: 1px solid #000;" id='password' name='password' size="10" onClick='changeStyle(this.id);' onBlur='checkFieldPassword();'></td>
                            <td><div id='divPassword'></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Retype Password:<sup style=' cursor: help' title="Password must have at least 6 characters">*</sup></td><td><input type="password" style="border: 1px solid #000;" name="retypePassword" id='retypePassword' size="10" onClick='changeStyle(this.id);' onBlur='checkFieldRetypePassword();'></td>
                            <td><div id='divRetypePassword'></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #000;" id='email' name='email' size="10" onClick='changeStyle(this.id);' onBlur='checkFieldEmail();'></td>
                            <td><div id='divEmail'></div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                  </form>
              </div>
```

javascript:

```
var registerForm=document.getElementById('registerForm'); // register form

function changeStyle(element)
{
    registerForm.element.style.border='1px solid #fff';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the element by ID:

```
document.getElementById(element).style.border = '1px solid #fff';
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the passed selector (assuming that you're passing the `id` as a string):

```
document.getElementById(element).style.border = '1px solid #fff';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A28Lf/) (in the Fiddle, I'm using a red border to make it more obvious, but the principle is exactly the same).

If you're passing the node *itself* in the function, however:

```
element.style.border = '1px solid #fff';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A28Lf/1/) (again, a red border for visual clarity).

Comment: I include the javascript script in the end of html file.
<script src="ajaxScript.js"></script>
PS: when i tryed to write: element.style.border=...
It says me that cannot read style of undefined(or something like that)

Comment: Ah, ok :D 
function changeStyle(element)
{
    }

Comment: I try to  send as a parametr form's element (onClick event from html file).

Comment: I showed it in my question ;)
Sorry i'm new on this forum. Maybe i'm doing something wrong?
BTW: Qantas 94 Heavy helped me whit this issue.

Comment: So you did; sorry: I appear to have gone blind... >_<